# Port forwarding fail - port open, but content not served

Tags: router, port-forwarding, port, nginx

I decided I would embark on the journey of trying to self-host a website, and I've run into some trouble.

I'm hosting the content on a local desktop using nginx. My router (a vtech) was assigned a static IP by the ISP, and I connected to the router and created port forwarding on port 80 for my web server. `localhost:80` confirms the content is being provided on port 80, and the rule on the router says TCP starting 80 ending 80 should hit destination port 80. An external port checker does seem to indicate that port 80 is open on the router (checking by IP).

(I don't know if this is relevant, and I'm having trouble finding a resource for this, but the router shows me that the connection is vdsl_ipv4, and the port is PTM over DSL. I see that there's an option to create a new connection. Do I need a different type of connection/port?)

But when I browse the IP, all I get is the router splash page, not the content being served on port 80. What might I be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to access it externally or internally?

Comment: @grawity I don't get the content whether I use the router's internal or external IP.

Comment: That's not what I meant – are you trying to access it **from inside or from outside**?

Comment: @grawity Sorry. Here's the setup: the content is hosted on a desktop, and when I use a browser on the same desktop, but try to access the content through a browser using anything other than `localhost`, I don't see the content. Does that help?

Comment: Sounds like an identical issue to https://superuser.com/questions/1504819/unable-to-access-local-server-using-fqdn-but-can-access-from-internet/.

Comment: @grawity I hadn't seen that one. I suspect that you're right. I'm going to try to work through that answer, and close this if it is indeed a duplicate. Thanks for the time.

Comment: If you are using your APs internal IP address to access the site, that will not work.  However, if you are using your external IP address to attempt to access the site and you are getting the AP control panel, you need to disable remote access or choose a different port to forward.

Comment: @grawity Something strange is still going on. Even with a new rule, I'm still not getting the content. I'll either get a 404 from nginx or the router's splash page.

Comment: @Ecstasy I can't find a remote access setting anywhere in the router's settings, unless SMB or DLNA count. I also sort of need it to be on this port, if at all possible.

Comment: If you get a 404 from Nginx, that's good – you're able to reach Nginx.

Comment: Try forwarding from a port other than 80.